# What cause format change when copy and paste in rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

```
#sample select
sample_frac(mydata,n%)#random select n% sample

##############data review####
```

Just copy above code into rstudio script, you will find 2 more `tab` added to the last line.
What cause it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**

As mentioned by @Jay in the comments, the `n%` in the command is treated as a function and since it is not complete it indents the next line.

To further confirm, try with `df %in%` in the script or `df >%>` and hit enter to see the cursor goes to the next line with an indent.

To avoid that just complete the function there.

```
sample_frac(mydata,n)
```

OR

```
sample_frac(mydata, n %% somenumber)
```

whatever you are trying to do and it should be fine.

**Original Answer**

It did add 2 tab spaces in the code when pasting in the RStudio script. I tried to paste the same text in my notes, Pycharm editor but it did not add any extra tabs there. So it was sure that this is a RStudio issue.

It turns out it is the indentation settings in RStudio which is responsible for this. To change that:

Go to Tools -> Global Options. Click on the Code option on the left. You'll see this :

[image]

Uncheck Auto-indent code after paste

[image]

and click on OK.

Now try to paste the same text. Should be resolved.

Comment: which  `%` is incorrect? even no package loaded, this problem still occur.